# # appears on url after deploy on gcloud

Tags: angular, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, routes

I recently deployed an app on google cloud using app engine and when visitin  http://myapp.domain.com/
a `#` appears before any of my routes in angular, something like this:

```
http://myapp.domain.com/#/dashboard
```

This is what my app.yaml currently has:

```
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

skip_files:
- ^(?!dist) 

handlers:
  - url: /
    secure: always
    static_files: dist/myapp/index.html
    upload: dist/myapp/index.html

  #  Routing rules for resources, css, js, images etc. Any file with format filename.ext
  - url: /(.*\.(.+))$
    secure: always
    static_files: dist/myapp/\1
    upload: dist/myapp/(.*\.(.+))$

  #  Routing rule for Angular Routing
  - url: /(.*)
    secure: always
    static_files: dist/myapp/index.html
    upload: dist/myapp/index.html
```

Comment: Are you sure that you didn't accidentally specify `{useHash: true}` in your RouterModule import? Maybe only for production builds? This would be my best guess based on the information provided,

Comment: @FabianStrathaus thanks, that was the problem!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just so this question can be closed successfully:
solution is to remove `{useHash: true}` from RouterModule config.